# Как прервать задачу?

Tags: c#

У меня есть телеграмм-бот, который принимает команду, после чего она выполняется бесконечно, пока не придет апдейт, а потом этот бесконечный цикл должен прерваться и приложение должно дальше работать(ждать команду). Я пытался сделать что-то на подобии этого:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
    if (message.Text == "/stop")
    {
        
        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Dispose();
        await client.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "end");
    }

    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
       
            while (true)
            {


                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;

                await _parserWorker.Work(message, client, message.Chat.Id);
                Thread.Sleep(60000);

            }
        

        Console.WriteLine("end");
    },ct);
```

Но приложение полностью падает. Если не передавать ct в Task, то прерывание не выполняется.

Как можно завершить цикл без падения приложения?

Comment: Приложения не падают из за цикла с задержкой в минуту. Найдите причину падения и пофиксите.

Comment: Но вообще, чтобы что то выполнять раз в минуту, я бы наверное использовал таймер, чем синхронный цикл. На крайняк асинхронный цикл и то лучше будет.

Comment: Здесь неправильно практически всё. Пример рабочей реализации по ссылке вверху над вопросом. Научитесь использовать `try-catch`.